# How to get Data from an Object in Java?

Tags: java

I have Some thing like this in java

```
Object dym=[{Auto Phrasing=false,
             New Term=buy, 
             Number of Results=21, 
             Spell Correction=true}];
```

That '**Object**' will always present those 4 properties(Those values are from Json response) . I want to pull the '**New Term**' value from there. How should i do it?

Comment: No. we are converting the JSon to JAva object. Still Java

Comment: This code does not compile in java.

Comment: This isn't java syntax, is this JSon code?

Comment: Yes it does. It looks like some sort of list. I just want the particular value from the 'New Term'

Comment: Yes. it is Json response and we are converting the json to java object through GSON library

Comment: Show your Java code then, not just the json response, especially since you're already converting the json object to a Java object.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Guys, Even though i got minus point for asking this questions, but based on the responses of the experts they brought to my attention that the response type i am dealing with json and not java array list. This Question served me a lot in figuring out my problem

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend encapsulating the array into a class, like this:

```
public class Something {
  public boolean autoPhrasing;
  public String newTerm;
  public int numResults;
  public boolean spellCorrection;

  // Constructor
  Something(boolean phrasing, String term, int results, boolean correct) {
    autoPhrasing = phrasing;
    newTerm = term;
    numResults = results;
    spellCorrection = correct;
  }
}
```

Then you can create a new `Something` object for every JSON object you encounter.

To get the value from this, you just need to call the field from the object, like this:

```
Something foo = new Something(false, "buy", 21, true);

boolean isPhrasing   = foo.autoPhrasing;
String term          = foo.newTerm;
int results          = foo.numResults;
boolean isCorrecting = foo.spellCorrection;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a Java JSon framework like Jackson. It can map a JSON structure to Java objects.

http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Comment: The link is broken. This is why you are advised to write and explain what is in the link in your answer and then add the link just for more details or as a source.